# Mantener un countDonwTimer activo al cerrar la actividad o la app

Tags: android, contador

Tengo un contador que realiza una cuenta atrás, pero al momento de salir de la actividad vuelve a reiniciar, deseo que esto no suceda, he pensado que tal vez tendré que conectar la app con una pagina web mediante un `ViewWeb`, pero seria mas tedioso, habrá otra solución ?

Les Dejo mi CountDown

```
inicar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.iniciar);
        inicar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countDown = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        contador.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                        contador.setText("Tiempo terminado!");
                    }
                }.start();
                inicar.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        pausar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Reinicar);
        pausar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countDown.cancel();
                inicar.setEnabled(true);
                contador.setText("Esperando minutos...");
            }
        });
```

Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un servicio que se queda activo aun se cierre la aplicacion. 
Para poder recibir la notificacion que da tick que hace el `CountDownTimer` desde el servicio, tienes que suscribirte al servicio.

Primero defines el servicio:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class CountDownService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String paquete_app = "nombrepaquete.countdown_broadcast";
    Intent bi = new Intent(paquete_app);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {       
            super.onCreate();

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                    sendBroadcast(bi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                   bi.putExtra("countdown", -1);
                   sendBroadcast(bi);
                }
            };

            countDownTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            countDownTimer.cancel();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {       
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {       
            return null;
        }
}
```

Ahora iniciamos el servicio y con el intent, le indicamos la referencia del Activity a la cual notificara por cada `Tick`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, CountDownService.class));
}

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
        actualizarContador(intent); 
    }
};

@Override  
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();        
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(CountDownService.paquete_app ));
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {        
    stopService(new Intent(this, CountDownService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void actualizarContador(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
        if(millisUntilFinished > 0)
        {

            // actualiza aqui tu contador en la vista
            contador.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }
        else{
            contador.setText("Tiempo terminado!");
        }
    }
}
```

Recuerda definir tu servicio en el manifest:

```
<service android:name=".CountDownService" />
```

Comment: No lo hacer funcionar el servicio, este de deberia activar cuando presione el boton de comenzar y destruirse en el boton de detener, Tengo mi countDonw en el boton ..

Comment: Que exactamente no funciona. No inicia o es que no se detiene?

Comment: No inicia ... la clase del servicio la copie tal cual como esta aqui, creo que el problema esta en la actividad donde muestra el contador

Comment: Te lanz algun error? Registraste el servicio en el manifest?

Comment: no no muestra ningún error, y si lo hice

Comment: Publica lo que hiciste para poder ayudarte. Si pudiera crear un chat te ayudaria mejor pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64323/discussion-between-ash-and-einer).